# Schema for chat application using mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, database-schema

I am trying to build a schema for chat application in `mongodb`. I have 2 types of user models - `Producer` and `Consumer`. Producer and Consumer can have conversations with each other. My ultimate goal is to fetch all the conversations for any producer and consumer and show them in a list, just like all the messaging apps (eg Facebook) do.

Here is the `schema` I have come up with:

```
Producer: {
    _id: 123,
    'name': "Sam"
}

Consumer:{
    _id: 456,
    name: "Mark"
}

Conversation: {
    _id: 321,
    producerId: 123,
    consumerId: 456,
    lastMessageId: 1111,
    lastMessageDate: 7/7/2018
}

Message: {
    _id: 1111,
    conversationId: 321,
    body: 'Hi'
}
```

Now I want to fetch say all the consersations of Sam. I want to show them in a list just like Facebook does, grouping them with 
each Consumer and sorting according to time.
I think I need to do following queries for this:

1) Get all Conversations where producerId is `123` sorted by lastMessageDate.
  I can then show the list of all Conversations.

2) If I want to know all the messages in a conversation, I make query on Message and get all messages where conversationId is `321`

Now, here for each new `message`, I also need to update the `conversation` with new messageId and date everytime. Is this the right way to proceed and is this optimal considering the number of queries involved. Is there a better way I can proceed with this?  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you have two types of User model. How do you know which message send by whom? For example does `Message` as `consumerId` and `producerId`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Design:**
I wouldn't say it's bad. Depending on the case you've described, it's actually pretty good. Such denormalization of last message date and ID is great, especially if you plan a view with a list of all conversations - you have the last message date in the same query. Maybe go even one step further and add last message text, if it's applicable in this view.

You can read more on pros and cons of denormalization (and schema modeling in general) on the MongoDB blog (parts [1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) and [3](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)). It's not that fresh but not outdated.

Also, if such multi-document updates might scary you with some possible inconsistencies, MongoDB v4 got you covered with [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/).

**Querying:**
On one hand, you can involve multiple queries, and it's not bad at all (especially, when few of them are easily cachable, like the producer or consumer data). On the other hand, you can use [aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to fetch all these things at once if needed.

Comment: What about deleting a conversation just for 1 user? How would you do it in mongodb ?

Comment: @G.Al you could store a `deletedFor: string[]` on a message.

Comment: That would work. I was just wondering how can I query to get all messages that are NOT deletedFor: req.user.id

Comment: @G.Al A simple `{deletedFor: {$ne: userId}}` will work, but may be a problem as you cannot index parallel arrays in MongoDB. Assuming that deleted messages won't be often, it should be OK.

Comment: I query them only via message collection. So I dont think there would be any problem. What do you think :) ?

Comment: @G.AI I really don't know. Just measure that and you'll be able to decide, whether it works for your case or not.